# match two columns in seperate sheets and add other two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, sumifs

I have 2 excel spreadsheets in a single excel file. Both of these files have a Campaign Name column and sum_revenues column

My first problem is that I want to match the Campaign Name column in both the sheets and if they match then I want to add the sum_revenues value in the 1st spreadsheet to sum_revenues in the 2nd spreadsheet

I know that sumif or sumifs will be used but I do not know how I can apply them.

The output should be the addition of sum_revenues column in both the sheets based on the Campaign name matching criteria in the sum_final column which is present on the 2nd sheet.
I hope I am clear about the question but please let me know if there is any confusion.

Below is how sheet 1, Sheet 2 looks like.

Sheet 1:

```
Campaign Name               sum_revenues
ABC                          40
DEF                          60
```

Sheet 2:

```
Campaign Name               sum_revenues           sum_final
ABC                          30                     70
GHI                          10                     0
```

Now please note that in Sheet 2 in which I want to output is that sum_final column has the sum_revenues added up from both the sheets because ABC is present in both the sheets and it should show 0 for those which do not match.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$3,2,FALSE),0)+B2
```

**Sheet 2 Images:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below formula may help you, assuming that your sheet1 data available in column A & B and sheet 2 data available in Column D & E and finally F would be  the result.

Type the formula 
sumif(e:e,d:d,a:a)+sumif(a:a,d:d,b:b) +e3